# Evaluation order of dictionary literals

Tags: python, dictionary

```
def key(): print 'key'
def val(): print 'val'

{key() : val()}
```

prints `val, key`, i.e. the value is evaluated first. Is this behaviour

- consistent across python versions and implementations?
- documented anywhere? (http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#dictionary-displays says nothing)

Comment: May be this is the reason : your code is equivalent to `dic[key()]=val()`. And in assignment operator the RHS is always evaluated first, so `'val'` gets printed first and then LHS is executed.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This section of the reference manual documents the order, but claims it is different than what you are seeing:  http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#evaluation-order

> In the following lines, expressions will be evaluated in the arithmetic order of their suffixes:

```
expr1, expr2, expr3, expr4
(expr1, expr2, expr3, expr4)
{expr1: expr2, expr3: expr4}
expr1 + expr2 * (expr3 - expr4)
expr1(expr2, expr3, *expr4, **expr5)
expr3, expr4 = expr1, expr2
```

And there is an open bug against the implementation about it:  [Evaluation order of dictionary display is different from reference manual](http://bugs.python.org/issue11205).

Comment: Thanks a lot! Funny how RH says there that no one has cared for eight years... And congrats for 100,000 points!

Answer (score 5):

It turns out that it's *not* consistent across implementations.

```
def p(x):
    print(x)
    return x

{p('k1'): p('v1'), p('k2'): p('v2'), p('k3'): p('v3')}
```

Gives:

```
Python 2.7.3 (default, Aug  1 2012, 05:16:07) 
IronPython 2.7.3 (2.7.0.40) on Mono 4.0.30319.1 (32-bit)
[PyPy 2.0.0-beta1 with GCC 4.4.3] on linux2

v1
k1
v2
k2
v3
k3
```

but

```
Jython 2.5.1+ (Release_2_5_1, Oct 31 2011, 11:44:27) 
[OpenJDK Server VM (Sun Microsystems Inc.)] on java1.6.0_27
Jython 2.7b1 (default:ac42d59644e9, Feb 9 2013, 15:24:52) 
[OpenJDK Server VM (Sun Microsystems Inc.)] on java1.6.0_27

k1
v1
k2
v2
k3
v3
```

Comment: Thanks, hope they get that fixed soon.