# Evaluation order guarantee within collection literals and function arguments

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6

In Python 3.6.1, all of the following seem to evaluate left-to-right:

```
In [1]: counter = iter(range(100))

In [2]: [next(counter), next(counter)]
Out[2]: [0, 1]

In [3]: (next(counter), next(counter))
Out[3]: (2, 3)

In [4]: next(counter), next(counter)
Out[4]: (4, 5)

In [5]: {next(counter): next(counter),
   ...:  next(counter): next(counter)}
   ...:  
Out[5]: {6: 7, 8: 9}

In [6]: print(next(counter), next(counter))
10 11
```

I observe that collections such as `list`, `tuple`, and `dict`, as well as function arguments, evaluate their arguments in a left-to-right fashion.

Is this behavior guaranteed, or is it an implementation detail? I imagine that it must be part of the language standard, because otherwise programs would evaluate differently depending on the interpreter.

Comment: How is this too broad? This is a well-defined question with a well-defined answer... Voting to leave open and +1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this behavior is part of the language standard. See section [Evaluation order](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#evaluation-order) in the docs:

> ## 6.15. Evaluation order
>
> Python evaluates expressions from left to right. Notice that while
>   evaluating an assignment, the right-hand side is evaluated before the
>   left-hand side.
>
> In the following lines, expressions will be evaluated in the
>   arithmetic order of their suffixes:
>
> ```
> expr1, expr2, expr3, expr4
> (expr1, expr2, expr3, expr4)
> {expr1: expr2, expr3: expr4}
> expr1 + expr2 * (expr3 - expr4)
> expr1(expr2, expr3, *expr4, **expr5)
> expr3, expr4 = expr1, expr2
> ```

In a related question about `dict` literals only, [one answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15681329/) points out that the actual behavior in CPython was incorrect for `dict` [since version 2.5](https://bugs.python.org/issue11205#msg128507) and was fixed in [version 3.5](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/changelog.html#python-3-5-0-beta-2).